# Converting Mahalanobis p1 probabilities to p2 probabilities - is vectorization possible in this context?

Tags: r, vectorization

I'm trying to write a function that takes in p1 probabilities for Mahalanobis distances and returns p2 probabilities. The formula for p2, along with a worked example is given at [on the IBM website](http://amosdevelopment.com/support/faq/mahalanobis-p2.html). I have written a function (below) that solves the problem, and allows me to reproduce the p2 values given in the worked example at the aforementioned webpage.

```
p1_to_p2 <- function(p1,N) {

  p2 <- numeric(length(p1))
  
  for (i in 1:length(p1))
  { 
    k <- i;
    p1_value <- p1[i];
    
    start_value <- 1;
    
    while (k >= 1)
    {
      start_value = start_value - choose(N,N-k+1) * (1-p1_value)^(N-k+1) * (p1_value)^(k-1)
      k <- k-1;
    }
    
    p2[i] <- start_value;
    
  } 
  
  return(p2)  
  
}

p1 <- c(.0046132,.0085718,.0390278,.0437704,.0475222)
N <- 73
p1_to_p2(p1,N)
```

Although the function works, it's been suggested to me by a colleague that it's inefficient/poorly written as it's not vectorized. This is indeed potentially relevant since in general we will be converting a lot more than just 5 p1 values to p2 values.

I have some limited experience vectorizing code, but I am wondering if a vectorized solution is possible in this context since within the loop the variable start_value constantly needs to update itself. If vectorization is not possible, is there some other way I should improve the code so that it works better?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it, Breaking the steps here can help(Please read the comments):

```
#Input: 
N <- 73
p1 <- c(.0046132,.0085718,.0390278,.0437704,.0475222)
n <- N:(N-length(p1)+1)

# code: 



mahalanobis_dist = function(x=x,n){
        m = max(n)
        max_min = Reduce(`*`,c(1, n[-length(n)]), accumulate = TRUE)
        acc = c(1, Reduce(`*`, seq_along(n), accumulate = TRUE)[-length(n)])
        comns = max_min/acc

        exp <- comns*((1 - x)**n)*(x**(m - n))
    return(1- sum(exp))
  } ## the calculation of Mahalanobis distances


## This is just an iterator for each of the sequences we have to run the above function
ls <-  lapply(n, function(x)(max(n):x))
## creating a list of iterators

## applying mapply, mapply or Map can iterate multiple inputs of the function,
## here the input p1 and ls , p1 is your input points, ls is the iterator created above 
mapply(mahalanobis_dist,p1, ls)
## Applying the function on each iterators


#Output:
#> mapply(mahalanobis_dist,p1, ls)
#[1] 0.2864785 0.1299047 0.5461263 0.3973690
#[5] 0.2662369
```

**Note:**

Also, one can join the last two steps like below, with one function and correct iteration this can be achieved:

```
mapply(mahalanobis_dist,p1, lapply(n, function(x)(max(n):x)))
```

Comment: Thanks! One thing I noticed, though, was that if I make `N <- 171` but keep everything else the same, the `p2` values all come out as `NaN`. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @user1205901-ReinstateMonica, wait let me check

Comment: Thanks, if I paste your code exactly I find it works. However, if I paste with one change `N <- 171` I get `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 21.4 Gb`

Comment: @user1205901-ReinstateMonica, yes I can see that, give me sometime I will optimize it for large numbers

Comment: @user1205901-ReinstateMonica, Please check it for your example now

Comment: @user1205901-ReinstateMonica, I still feel that your implementation is better in terms of performance, wait for more answers, someone might give you a faster implemenation